# How to calculate number of digits before and after decimal point?

Tags: c++, loops, decimal-point

Today a question was asked in my c++ class test. "Write a program that inputs a floating point number and calculates the number of digits before and after decimal point."

I calculated numbers before decimal points with this code:

```
float n;

cin>>n;

float temp = n;

int count = 0;

while(temp1 > 1) {

    count++;

    temp = temp/10;
}

cout<<count;
```

but I stuck with after part. Can anyone tell me how to do this? or can provide the whole program?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use a [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the `.` and then you can get how many "digits" are before and after it

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope. I cant use strings.

Comment: _"or can provide the whole program?"_ Seriously?

Comment: Solve with string regardless of assignment requirements because it is easier. Once you know how you did it with string, you should be able to adapt the logic to use a `char` array and meet the assignment requirements.

Comment: @user4581301 _"... because it is easier ..."_ Easier than what actually? Is that really a good reasoning? The problem is that there isn't really a solution to get user input congruent with the internal `float` representation of fraction digits IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  `string` is easier than a char array. Perhaps there is some unwritten rule that such assignments use that ancient version of C++ with `iostream.h` and without standardized `<string>`.

Comment: @anatolyg What please?? Was anything you mention ever in question?

Comment: Apologies for a poorly worded comment. As πάνταῥεῖ points out below, either a fixed point representation or a string representation of the number will be required. A string representation is likely more available than fixed point, so start with a string. `std::string` is easier to get to work without side-bugs like buffer overruns distracting from the main goal than a `char` array, so start with `std::string`. Once you have an algorithm that works with `std::string`, then rework the good algorithm to use a `char` array.

Comment: @user4581301 Seems the most viable way to leave string and character representations behind, is using a _fixed decimal point_ representation. But it looks that the professor / teacher / tutor failed to do their job well, unless the OP was rephrasing the given task wrong and totally misunderstood it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Write a program that inputs a floating point number and calculates the number of digits before and after decimal point.

Well, as is that task is asking for something not really solvable using a `float` and standard c++, because the binary representation of a `float` values exponent and mantissa isn't defined in the c++ standard.
Hence you can't know how many digits will be used to represent the fraction part of the number, unless you know how exactly the c++ compiler implemented `float` (or `double`) binary representations.

Most probably the implementation is optimized for the target CPU and its capabilities how to deal with floating point values.

---

So the only chance you have is to read the number as a `std::string` representation in 1st place, count the digits that appear before and after the `'.'` character, and finally convert the `std::string` variable to a `float` value.

---

Here's a simple illustration what I meant in the 1st part of my answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    std::istringstream iss("3.1415"); // same as reading from cin
    std::cout << "Input: " << iss.str() << std::endl;
    float temp;
    iss >> temp;
    std::cout << "Internal representation: " 
              << std::fixed << std::setprecision(22) << temp << std::endl;
    float fraction = temp - abs(temp);
    int fractiondigits = 0;
    while(fraction > std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()) { // epsilon is the smallest 
                                                              // value that can be 
                                                              // represented in binary form
        fraction *= 10.0f;
        fraction -= abs(fraction);
        ++fractiondigits;            
    }
    std::cout << "Number of digits used in the representation: " 
              << fractiondigits << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
Input: 3.1415
Internal representation: 3.1414999961853027343750
Number of fraction digits used in the representation: 21
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8455cd726436fcb0)

---

So you see that's not congruent with the user's input.

I don't know if your professors intend was to ask about and letting you acknowledge this incongruence of user input and internal representation of `float`.
But as mentioned the actual count of digits is compiler implementation and platform dependent, so there's no definite answer for the number of fraction digits.

Comment: I reckon that if the students get so far as to learn all that, the professor has more than achieved what they would ever hoped for.

Comment: @Walter Don't really _reckon_ on that. There are many professors / teachers / tutors, who convey totally wrong stuff and misconceptions. It's a question of competence.

Answer (score 0):

The question is fundamentally **irrelevant**. Most real numbers have infinitely many digits, but computer represented numbers must have a finite representation. For the common case of a binary representation, the represented number also has a finite decimal representation. However, truncating this decimal representation at fewer digits (as few as `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10` to be precise) still obtains the same representable number. Thus, the relevant number of digits for computer floating-point numbers best refers to their binary rather than their decimal representation. This is given by `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits` (total: in front of and after the point).